# VBA Runtime Error 9 (Excel 2007)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range, runtime

i have got the following problem. I am creating an excel worksheet with active x elements to calculate several values (for a class in university). And in the following code i sometimes (not everytime) get the runtime error 9 that the index is out of range (hopefully i translated it correctly into english). I am new to vba. I know that there are several similar problems already asked but i have a huge problem to adapt the solutions to my code as i don't really understand either the problem in my code as also the solutions of their problems.

I marked the line for which the error occurs with stars.

I would be really thankful if anybody could explain, why this problem occurs in my code sometimes and how to solve it properly.
Thank you in advance.

Here's the code:

```
Sub calcinull()
Dim ione(4), itwo(4), ii, ints(4), cs(4), io, it As Double
Dim a, b, c As Double

ione(0) = 0
ione(1) = 10
ione(2) = 20
ione(3) = 30
ione(4) = 40

itwo(0) = 100
itwo(1) = 90
itwo(2) = 80
itwo(3) = 70
itwo(4) = 60


For b = 0 To 4
    ii = ione(b) + (((itwo(b) - ione(b)) * (NPV(ione(b))) / (NPV(ione(b)) - NPV(itwo(b)))))
    ints(b) = ii
    cs(b) = NPV(ii)
Next b

Dim AbsInt(4), AbsCs(4) As Double

For a = 0 To 4
    AbsInt(a) = VBA.Abs(ints(a))
    AbsCs(a) = VBA.Abs(cs(a))
Next a

Dim pos As Integer

pos = Application.Match(Application.Min(AbsCs), AbsCs, 0)

*ii = ints(pos)*

If NPV(ii) > 0 Then
    io = ii
    If pos > 0 Then
        it = itwo(pos - 1)
    Else
        it = itwo(0)
    End If
ElseIf NPV(ii) < 0 Then
    it = ii
    If pos > 0 Then
        io = ione(pos - 1)
    Else
        io = ione(0)
    End If
ElseIf NPV(ii) = 0 Then
    inull = ii
End If

For c = 1 To 30
    Do Until (NPV(io) - NPV(it)) <> 0
        io = io - 0.1
        it = it + 0.1
    Loop
        ii = io + (((it - io) * (NPV(io)) / (NPV(io) - NPV(it))))
        If NPV(ii) > 0 Then
            io = ii
            If it > (io + 0.5) Then
                it = it - 0.5
            End If
        ElseIf NPV(ii) < 0 Then
            it = ii
            If io < (it - 0.5) Then
                io = io + 0.5
            End If
        ElseIf NPV(ii) = 0 Then
            inull = ii
            Exit For
        End If
Next c
inull = ii

End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't `NPV` needs 2 parameters ? `Rate` and `ValueArray()` ?

Comment: NPV is an UDF which requires the Rate as variable as the variable is used to discount the cash flows given. I am not that good and used to vba as i could tell, but i don't really see how a ValueArray could be used in NPV. Can you explain your idea to me, please? 
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As `ints` is an array with 5 elements (0..4), probably `pos` is > 4 when this error occurs.

If you can't tell why, maybe put something like this behind the `Match`-Statement and set a breakpoint to the `print` while testing.

```
if pos < 0 or pos > 4 then
    debug.print pos & " is off"
end if
```

Comment: Okay. That this is the problem seems somehow logical, but the question is, why does it occur. Especially as the arrays before ("ints" and "cs" and therefor "AbsInt" and "AbsCs") have the same length as they are filled in the same loop. And the "pos" variable should just give the position of the minimum value of the absolutes of Cs and then in return i want the value of the Int-Array at this position. I don't understand what the code does wrong. :(

Answer (score 0):

Alright guys, i solved it. The problem was, that the arrays uses indices from 0 to x, whereas the position gives the nth position of the array, which means, that my "pos"-variable is always one integer above the array-index.

Thank you all for your help!